# Query for age in sparql

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, dbpedia

I am writing a query that calculates the age of someone knowing their birthdate and deathdate. I want to ask for a certain artist (in this case Michael Jackson). The problem is that I can't reuse the birthdate and deathdate in the following query:

```
select ?artist ?age  
where { 
  dbr:Michael_Jackson dbo:birthDate ?birthdate .

  dbr:Michael_Jackson dbo:deathDate ?deathdate . 

  bind( year(?deathdate) - year(?birthdate) - if(month(?deathdate)<month(?birthdate) || (month(?deathdate)=month(?birthdate) && day(?deathdate<day(?birthdate)),1,0) as ?age)
}
```

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: the error is `Virtuoso 22003 Error SR586: Incomplete RDF box as argument 0 for year().` - I guess this happens because of a wrong lexical form of the date literal

Comment: You said you "can't reuse the birthdate and deathdate." Why not? Please post any error message you're getting, as I see something different than @AKSW.

Comment: @TallTed the query in the question fails because of some syntax errors, but the correct query fails because of the error I've shown in my comment above: `select ?artist ?age
where { 
values ?artist {dbr:Michael_Jackson}
   ?artist dbo:birthDate ?birthdate .

  ?artist dbo:deathDate ?deathdate . 

  bind( year(?deathdate) - year(?birthdate) - if(month(?deathdate)<month(?birthdate) || (month(?deathdate) < month(?birthdate) && day(?deathdate)< day(?birthdate)),1,0) as ?age)
}`

Answer (score 0):

I edited the query a bit to get [the values you're calculating against](http://prefix%20%20dbr:%20%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/%3E%20prefix%20%20dbo:%20%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/%3E%20%20select%20%20%20#%20?artist%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?birthdate%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?deathdate%20#%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?age%20%20%20where%20%7B%20%20%20%20dbr:Michael_Jackson%20%20%20dbo:birthDate%20%20?birthdate%20;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo:deathDate%20%20?deathdate%20.%20%20%20#%20%20%20bind(%20year(?deathdate)%20-%20year(?birthdate)%20-%20if(month(?deathdate)%3Cmonth(?birthdate)%20%7C%7C%20(month(?deathdate)=month(?birthdate)%20&&%20day(?deathdate)%3Cday(?birthdate)),1,0)%20as%20?age%20)%20%7D) --

```
birthdate                                              deathdate
"1958-8-29"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date>   "2009-6-25"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date>
```

The error you're hitting is because these are not valid `xsd:date` literals -- which require 2 digits for the month.

This data issue has been fixed on Wikipedia and so on DBpedia-Live, and your query works there, as [you can see](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=prefix%20%20dbr%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20%20dbo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20%20%20%23%20%3Fartist%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fbirthdate%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fdeathdate%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fage%20%20%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20dbr%3AMichael_Jackson%20%20%20dbo%3AbirthDate%20%20%3Fbirthdate%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3AdeathDate%20%20%3Fdeathdate%20.%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bind%28%20year%28%3Fdeathdate%29%20-%20year%28%3Fbirthdate%29%20-%20if%28month%28%3Fdeathdate%29%3Cmonth%28%3Fbirthdate%29%20%7C%7C%20%28month%28%3Fdeathdate%29%3Dmonth%28%3Fbirthdate%29%20%26%26%20day%28%3Fdeathdate%29%3Cday%28%3Fbirthdate%29%29%2C1%2C0%29%20as%20%3Fage%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20).  There are other issues with DBpedia-Live data (such as multiple versions of the abstract being shown, when you really only want to see the latest), but perhaps this solves your immediate need.